# Remove introduced padding to the start and end of a document in word using a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently writing up a macro which compares the contents of a word document against text dictionary file. It highlights all the matches so that the person can make appropriate changes. I'm a little new to macros so I used something similar I found online as a guide as well as my general coding knowhow but I don't know all the methods and objects that I need to.

I have set it up to open a common dialog to choose a word file to compare (the dictionary file is hard coded because I don't want people accidentally choosing one as it could potentially be used by a lot of people)

For each line in the dictionary file, the macro uses the hithighlight method to highlight any occurences of that word in the file. I had to put spaces around the word to make sure only individual words were done since the dictionary contained many acronyms.

The issue is I therefore had to pad the document with spaces at the start and end so that the first and last words are also checked, I'm not sure how to do this though. I've done some searching and I've seen a few things about using different selections but I don't know if there's a clone method for selections and I'm sure if I set another selection as equal to mine it'd just copy the address to the object which would make it pointless.

this is the code I have:

```
Documents(ActiveDocument.FullName).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

'Values for objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ColourYellow = 65535

Dim doc As Document
Dim DocRange As Range

'allows us to change the document in use
Set ObjCD = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Relevant path to the Dictionary txt file, change this to point to the dictionary list if different to this
DicFilePath = "O:\IPS\PDU\KIS\Intranet\consistency-with-styleguide-project\styleguidelist.txt"

'Set the parameters for the Common Dialog
ObjCD.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx" 'Filter only docx files
ObjCD.FilterIndex = 3
ObjCD.InitialDir = "" 'Set the initial path for the Common Dialog to the same folder as the script

'Display the File open dialog
InitFSO = ObjCD.ShowOpen

If InitFSO = False Then
    'No file was selected so Error
    MsgBox ("No file was selected")
Else
    'ScanFilePath =  the full path and filename if the file
    ScanFilePath = ObjCD.FileName

    Set doc = Documents.Open(ScanFilePath) 'store the document we want to check as doc
    Set objDicFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(DicFilePath, ForReading) 'open the dictionary file

    With doc
        MatchFound = False 'initially have no matches found as haven't searched yet
        Set DocRange = .Range 'this represents the entire document
        DicWordCount = 0

        DocRange.InsertAfter (Space(1))
        DocRange.InsertBefore (Space(1))
        'do this to pad the start and end with spaces to allow matches for the first and last word
        'this is done as it's easier than having it look for start and end of file markers and still only find
        'whole words

        'Loop though each word in the dictionary and check if that word exists in the word doc
        Do While objDicFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
            'reset so EACH word in dictionary is checked for
            DicWordFound = False

            'Read the next word from the dictionary
            DicWord = objDicFile.ReadLine
            DicWord = Space(1) & DicWord & Space(1) 'add a space to both sides to find whole words only

            DicWordFound = DocRange.Find.HitHighlight(DicWord, ColourYellow)
            'is true if it was found at least once, else false. If any are found they are highlighted in yellow

            If DicWordFound Then
                MatchFound = True 'MatchFound if used to check if any match was found for any words, only false if none are found
            End If
        Loop

        'this is done to remove the superfluous space at the end.

    End With

    If MatchFound Then
        'If a Match is found

        'Display OK message
        MsgBox ("Complete: MATCH FOUND!" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Matches are highlighted in yellow.")
    Else
        'If a Match is NOT found
        MsgBox ("No Match")
    End If
End If
```

if someone knows how I could remove the padding I added once I'm done searching that would be really helpful. Alternatively, if someone could suggest a more efficient way it would be greatly appreciated. (for instance, I'm sure there should be a way to check for whole words only when searching but I don't know it as I'm new to macros)

Also if someone knows for sure if the same functionality is replicated in word 97-2003 using the same methods and objects let me know, that way I can just extend it to .doc files without any extra word.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to record macros, this can help finding objects or method when you can't choose which is the right one.

In your case, you could use the .MatchWholeWord property of the Find object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226067.aspx) :

```
DicWordFound = DocRange.Find.HitHighlight(DicWord, ColourYellow, MatchWholeWord = True)
```

Could not check it right here though.

Hope that helps,

Regards,

Max

Comment: Perfect, I knew there would have been a better way to do that, it was really frustrating to know that there must have been a proper way to do it but having to do it a silly way because of lack of practice with macros.

It finds words correctly everywhere included the start and end and is limitted to whole words only. Thanks so much.